# How to assign table data source from specific attribute of response in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple typescript method to get a list and a status and my model is:

```
export interface CashPaymentModel  {
  success: boolean;
  data: CashSpendAdHocDTO[];
}
export interface CashSpendAdHocDTO  {
  dueDate: string;
  gross: string;
  moveStageName: string;
  paidDate: string;
  service: string;
  status: string;
  timestamp: string;
  type: string;
}
```

My service method is :

```
getCashPayments(policyVersionId: number, employeeId: number): Observable<CashPaymentModel> {
    return this.http.get<CashPaymentModel>(`/api/v1/policy/configuration/versions/${policyVersionId}/details?employeeId=${employeeId}`);
  }
```

In template, i want to show the list in response(second attribute in response) in a table but how can i assign this table data source?

```
tableDataSource: Observable<CashPaymentModel>;

testMethod() {
    this.tableDataSource = this.cashPaymentService.getCashPayments(this.policyVersionId, this.employeeId).subscribe((data: CashPaymentModel) => {
      this.tableDataSource = data; .......BLA BLA BLA
    });
  }
```

In ts, how can i assign tableDataSource properly from the second attribute of the response?

Comment: What do you mean by `second attribute of the response?`

Comment: first att of the response is status right, the second one is a list, so my table data source must be this list so i dont care about status i only need the list in model(CashSpendAdHocDTO )

Comment: `console.log(data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter first for undefined responses, and assign `tableDataSource` to the `data` attribute of `response` in case of `success` - (according to your interface).

Try this:

```
tableDataSource: Observable<CashPaymentModel>;

testMethod() {
    this.tableDataSource = this.cashPaymentService.getCashPayments(this.policyVersionId, this.employeeId).pipe(
      filter(res => res !== undefined),
    ).subscribe((res: CashPaymentModel) => {
      if (res.success) {
        this.tableDataSource = res.data;
      } else {
        // handle false success
        // usually you should not send 200 response code for false success and handle it in 
        // err block of subscribe
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per you interface structure, you can try:

```
testMethod() {
    this.tableDataSource = this.cashPaymentService.getCashPayments(this.policyVersionId, this.employeeId).subscribe((data: CashPaymentModel) => {
      this.tableDataSource = data.data;
    });
}
```